# File (PDF) is shown in browser instead of downloaded as attachment with Spring MVC Controller

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I'm trying to use a Spring MVC Controller to download a PDF file (see the code below).
However, despite the use of 'Content-Disposition', the PDF file shows in the browser (Chrome/Firefox/Internet Explorer). Instead, I want a 'Save as' dialog to be shown. Does anyone see what's wrong with my code, or do I need additional spring configuration for this to work?

```
@Controller
public class PdfController {

  @Autowired
  private PdfService pdfService;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/" + "temp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public void downloadPdf(final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,
        TemplateException, DocumentException {

    InputStream pdfInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
            pdfService.createPdf());
    IOUtils.copy(pdfInputStream, response.getOutputStream());

    String filename = "CustomFileName.pdf";
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="
            + filename.replace(" ", "_"));
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.flushBuffer();
  }

}
```

Comment: Try setting the response headers before sending the content. Also, IE (at least some older versions) will ignore the content-type header. For that, the request URL must end with ".pdf"

Comment: Setting the response headers before sending the content actually works, thanks!

Comment: Instead of void use byte[] or OutputStream  and return response.getOutputStream();